# Python - Logical Tests on Graph Data with NetworkX

Tags: python, graph, networkx

I would like to parse a large set of DiGraph data and perform some logical tests on it. The data looks like:

```
Source,Target,DateTime

a,b,201212100401
a,d,201212100403
b,e,201212100511
b,c,201212100518
e,f,201212100610
c,a,201212100720
```

The DataTime stamp is YYYYMMDDhhmm ...

I have some logic that I'm looking for such as find: Instances where A and C talk but not before (A and B) the (B and C). So the print out would be like:

```
Time 1| Time 2| Time 3
a,b,201212100401| b,c,201212100518| c,a,201212100720
```

I assume I could treat these as something like networkx objects with:

```
import networkx as nx
import sys

G = nx.DiGraph()

for line in (open(sys.argv[1])):
    n1, n2, t1 = line.split(',')
    G.add_edge(n1, n2, time=t1)
```

Now that the data is stored in G, I'm not sure how I would go about querying for A,B then B,C then C,A relationship.

Does anyone have any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is one way to do it:

```
import networkx as nx

data = '''a,b,201212100401
a,d,201212100403
b,e,201212100511
b,c,201212100518
e,f,201212100610
c,a,201212100720'''.split('\n')

G = nx.DiGraph()
for line in data:
    n1, n2, t1 = line.split(',')
    G.add_edge(n1, n2, time=t1)

def check_sequence(list_of_edges):
    times = []
    # First check if all the edges are in the graph
    # and collect their times in a list
    for e in list_of_edges:
        if e in G.edges():
            times.append(G[e[0]][e[1]]['time'])
        else:
            return "Edge {} not in the graph.".format(str(e))
    # Next check if each successive time in the list 
    # is greater than the previous time
    start = times[0]
    for time in times[1:]:
        if time > start:
            start = time
        else:
            return 'Edges not in sequence: {}'.format(str(times))
    # If we have not returned up to now, then we are in sequence
    return 'Edges are in sequence: {}'.format(str(times))

print check_sequence( [('a', 'e'), ('e', 'f'), ('a', 'f') ] )
# Edge ('a', 'e') not in the graph.
print check_sequence( [('a', 'b'), ('b', 'c'), ('c', 'a') ] )
# Edges are in sequence: ['201212100401', '201212100518', '201212100720']
print check_sequence( [('c', 'a'), ('a', 'b'), ('b', 'c') ] )
# Edges not in sequence: ['201212100720', '201212100401', '201212100518']
```

Comment: Ok I can wrap my head around that.. and I think I can modify it for a number of other cases where the logic varies. Thank you for the guidance.